# Is it possible to run wine-launcher-creator on modern Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, wine, .desktop

On previous Ubuntu versions like 18.04 LTS I was able to install [WINE Launcher Creator](http://code.google.com/p/wine-launcher-creator/).

But on modern Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it is not installable with the following messages:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/wine-launcher-creator/wine-launcher-creator_1.0.8-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./wine-launcher-creator_1.0.8-1_all.deb

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'wine-launcher-creator' instead of './wine-launcher-creator_1.0.8-1_all.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-launcher-creator : Depends: python-qt4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem caused by the fact that `python-qt4` package [does not in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-qt4).

So we need to add special [Qt4 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4) and install using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt-assistant-compat/libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-qt4/python-qt4_4.12.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-qt4_4.12.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb

wget -c https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/wine-launcher-creator/wine-launcher-creator_1.0.8-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./wine-launcher-creator_1.0.8-1_all.deb
```

and then enjoy the WINE Launcher Creator application.